# How do I create this table in a horizontal format?

Tags: tables

It is very important for me to make this table, and the truth is that I do not understand how to make this table in a horizontal format. I have made the drawings in latexdraw.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! The answer to your question is: with sufficient skill and patience. You will tremendously increase the chances of getting a good and timely answer if you show us what you have tried such that we do not have to punch in the text from a screen shot.

Comment: This is not a question; it is a work order.

Comment: What do you mean by *"horizontal format"*? Rotated 90 degrees with respect to the rest of the text?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This may give you a start. I just reproduced the parabola part (without really typing in the formulae nor the text). IMHO the rest is repetition and typing in the correct text. This example illustrates how you can color a row, make cells stretch over more than one column and draw pictures with some braces. In the other pictures you merely need to adjust the function (`declare function=...`) or just draw a circle or an ellipse. Each of the tasks is straightforward yet tedious.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{|l*{6}{|c}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c}{text} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{$A x^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{~} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{Parabola} & text & text & text & &text \\
Vertical & $\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
& $\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[1em] V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)\end{array}$ 
& $LR=4p$ & &\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
function={f(\x)=0.3*\x*\x+0.5;},decoration={brace,raise=1pt}]
\draw (-2.2,0) -- (2.2,0) (0,-0.5) -- (0,2);
\draw plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=-2:2] (\x,{f(\x)});
\draw ({-sqrt(5/3)},1) -- ({sqrt(5/3)},1);
\draw[decorate] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) node[midway,left,font=\tiny]{$p$};
\draw[decorate] (0,0.5) -- (0,1) node[midway,left,font=\tiny]{$p$};
\end{tikzpicture}} \\[2em]
\cline{1-6}
Horizontal & $\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
& $\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[1em] V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)\end{array}$ 
& $LR=4p$ & \\[2em]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also be looking for a `sidewaystable`. So just in case. The texts are still nonsensical but the figures are in (except for the annotations which are unreadable).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document} 
\begin{sidewaystable}
 \tikzset{every picture/.append style={decoration={brace,raise=1pt},
   nodes={font=\tiny},execute at end picture={\path ([yshift=0.5ex]current
   bounding box.north) ([yshift=-0.5ex]current
   bounding box.south);}}}
 \scriptsize
 \begin{tabular}{|l*{6}{|c}}
  \hline
   \multicolumn{3}{|c}{text} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{$A x^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|c}{~} \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!10}
   \multicolumn{2}{|l}{Parabola} & text & text & text & &text \\
   Vertical & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
   & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[1em] V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)\end{array}$ 
   & $LR=4p$ & &\multirowcell{2}[1.1em][t]{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
    function={f(\x)=0.3*\x*\x+0.5;}]
   \draw (-2.2,0) -- (2.2,0) (0,-0.5) -- (0,2);
   \draw plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=-2:2] (\x,{f(\x)});
   \draw ({-sqrt(5/3)},1) -- ({sqrt(5/3)},1);
   \draw[decorate] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) node[midway,left,font=\tiny]{$p$};
   \draw[decorate] (0,0.5) -- (0,1) node[midway,left,font=\tiny]{$p$};
   \end{tikzpicture}} 
   \\[2em]
  \cline{1-6}
   Horizontal & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
   & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[1em] V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)\end{array}$ 
   & $LR=4p$ & 
  \\[2em]
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!10}
   \multicolumn{2}{|l}{Circle} & text & text & Radius & &text \\
   $A=C=1$ & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
   & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[1em] V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)\end{array}$ 
   & $LR=4p$ & $R=\frac{\sqrt{D^2+E^2-4F}}{2}$  &
   $\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1.2cm];
   \node[above] at (0,1.2) {Circle};
   \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (-1.2,0) node[midway,above]{Radius};
   \end{tikzpicture}}}$
  \\[2em]
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!10}
   \multicolumn{2}{|l}{Ellipse} & text & text & text & &text \\
   Vertical & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
   & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[1em] V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)\end{array}$ 
   & $LR=4p$ & & \multirowcell{2}[0em][t]{\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) circle[x radius=1.5cm,y radius=0.8cm];
   \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (-1.5,0) node[midway,above]{$x$ radius};
   \end{tikzpicture}}
   \\[2em]
  \cline{1-6}
   Horizontal & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
   & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[1em] V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)\end{array}$ 
   & $LR=4p$ & 
  \\[2em]
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!10}
   \multicolumn{2}{|l}{Hyperbola} & text & text & text & &text \\
   Vertical & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
   & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[0.5em] V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)
   \\[0.5em] \multicolumn{3}{c}{\text{Asymptote}:\rho_\mathrm{dent}}\end{array}$ 
   & $LR=4p$ & &\multirowcell{2}[1.5em][t]{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
    function={f(\x)=(1.2/1.5)*sqrt(\x*\x-0.25);}]
    \draw[dashed] (-1.5,-1.2) -- (1.5,1.2) (-1.5,1.2) -- (1.5,-1.2);
    \draw plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=0.5:1.5] (\x,{f(\x)});
    \draw plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=0.5:1.5] (-\x,{f(\x)});
    \draw plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=0.5:1.5] (\x,{-f(\x)});
    \draw plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=0.5:1.5] (-\x,{-f(\x)});
   \end{tikzpicture}} 
   \\[2em]
  \cline{1-6}
   Horizontal & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} A&\ne&0 \\ C&=&0\end{array}$ & $x^2=\pm4py$
   & $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}} (x-h)^2&=&\pm4p(y-k) \\[0.5em] 
   V(x,k)& &F(p,\pm h)\\[0.5em]
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\text{Asymptote}:\rho_\mathrm{dent}} \end{array}$ 
   & $LR=4p$ & 
  \\[2em]
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this is the rotated view. In your document it will be sideways.

Comment: By the way, +1 :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Mille grazie! ;-)

Comment: @marmot +1 also for me!!! Great!!!

Comment: wow! Amazing work, thank you very much for the response.

Comment: Done!, thank you.