# How do draw inside a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'd like to reproduce such a table with variable lengths of lines and columns, and also with some pictures inside. It seems to be a mix between Tikz and tabular, but I don't know how to do such a table. Would you have any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome teo TeX.SX!  Pictures produced by Ti*k*Z are boxes exactly as characters are: there’s no particular problem implied in mixing them with ordinary text.  Could you be more specific about what your problem is?  What did you try thus far, and whare you got stuck?

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494078) may give you an idea.